# Client get message from server using asyncio in python

Tags: python, python-asyncio

We are trying to use asyncio to run a straightforward client/server. The server is an echo server with two possible commands sent by the client, *"quit"* and ***"timer"***. The **timer** command starts a timer that will print a message in the console every second (at the server and client), and the *quit* command closes the connection.

The actual problem is the following:

When we run the server and the client, and we start the timer, the result of the *timer* is not sent to the client. It blocks the server and the client.
I believe that the problem is on the client's side. However, I was not able to detect it.

### Server

```
import asyncio
import time

HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 9999

class Timer(object):
    '''Simple timer class that can be started and stopped.'''
    def __init__(self, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter, name = None, interval = 1) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.interval = interval
        self.writer = writer

    async def _tick(self) -> None:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(self.interval)
            delta = time.time() - self._init_time
            self.writer.write(f"Timer {delta} ticked\n".encode())
            self.writer.drain()
            print("Delta time: ", delta)

    async def start(self) -> None:
        self._init_time = time.time()
        self.task = asyncio.create_task(self._tick())

    async def stop(self) -> None:
        self.task.cancel()
        print("Delta time: ", time.time() - self._init_time)

async def msg_handler(reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter) -> None:
    '''Handle the echo protocol.'''
    # timer task that the client can start:
    timer_task = False

    try:
        while True:

            data = await reader.read(1024) # Read 256 bytes from the reader. Size of the message
            msg = data.decode() # Decode the message

            addr, port = writer.get_extra_info("peername") # Get the address of the client
            print(f"Received {msg!r} from {addr}:{port!r}")

            send_message = "Message received: " + msg
            writer.write(send_message.encode()) # Echo the data back to the client
            await writer.drain()  # This will wait until everything is clear to move to the next thing.

            if data == b"quit" and timer_task is True:
                # cancel the timer_task (if any)
                if timer_task:
                    timer_task.cancel()
                    await timer_task
                writer.close()  # Close the connection
                await writer.wait_closed()  # Wait for the connection to close


            elif data == b"quit" and timer_task is False:
                writer.close() # Close the connection
                await writer.wait_closed() # Wait for the connection to close

            elif data == b"start" and timer_task is False:
                print("Starting timer")
                t = Timer(writer)
                timer_task = True
                await t.start()

            elif data == b"stop" and timer_task is True:
                print("Stopping timer")
                await t.stop()
                timer_task = False

    except ConnectionResetError:
        print("Client disconnected")


async def run_server() -> None:
    # Our awaitable callable.
    # This callable is ran when the server recieves some data
    server = await asyncio.start_server(msg_handler, HOST, PORT)

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop() # new_event_loop() is for python 3.10. For older versions, use get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run_server())
```

### Client

```
import asyncio

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 9999


async def run_client() -> None:
    # It's a coroutine. It will wait until the connection is established
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection(HOST, PORT)

    while True:

        message = input('Enter a message: ')
        writer.write(message.encode())
        await writer.drain()

        data = await reader.read(1024)
        if not data:
            raise Exception('Socket not communicating with the client')
        print(f"Received {data.decode()!r}")

        if (message == 'quit'):
            writer.write(b"quit")
            writer.close()
            await writer.wait_closed()
            exit(2)
            # break # Don't know if this is necessary


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run_client())
```

Comment: Possible solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/29102047/2823755](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29102047/2823755). A few answers suggest using aioconsole package - [https://stackoverflow.com/a/48865532/2823755](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48865532/2823755).  Search with `python asyncio input blocks site:stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a possible solution, by separating the thread.

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

async def send_msg(websocket):
    while True:
        imp = await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, lambda: input("Enter something: "))
        print("MESSAGE: ", imp)
        await websocket.send(imp)
        #return imp

async def recv_msg(websocket):
    while True:
        msg = await websocket.recv()
        print(f":> {msg}")


async def echo_loop():
    uri = f"ws://localhost:8765"
    async with websockets.connect(uri, ssl=None) as websocket:
        while True:
           await asyncio.gather(recv_msg(websocket),send_msg(websocket))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(echo_loop())
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: `run_in_executor` is a tidy solution.

Answer (score 2):

The client blocks on the input() function.  This question is similar to [server stop receiving msg after 1 msg receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69715462/server-stop-receiving-msg-after-1-msg-receive)

Comment: Is this question a duplicate of the link in your answer?

Comment: It is very similar; I believe the cause is the same but the code and symptoms are a bit different, which makes it not entirely obvious.  In the first question, the client isn't sending; in this question, the client isn't receiving.  Underlying cause is the same: you can't use the `input()` function on the same thread as a running asyncio loop.  If you think that's a duplicate you can mark it so.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no clear solution. In particular, there have been many changes in python since the early releases of asyncio, so many possible solutions are outdated.

I change the code to use WebSockets. However, the problem persists: ***input*** blocks the code, and none of the solutions above have solved my problem.

Below is the new version of the code (and the error remains):

### Server

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import time

class Timer(object):
    '''Simple timer class that can be started and stopped.'''

    def __init__(self, websocket, name=None, interval=1) -> None:
        self.websocket = websocket
        self.name = name
        self.interval = interval

    async def _tick(self) -> None:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(self.interval)
            await self.websocket.send("tick")
            print("Delta time: ", time.time() - self._init_time)

    async def start(self) -> None:
        self._init_time = time.time()
        self.task = asyncio.create_task(self._tick())

    async def stop(self) -> None:
        self.task.cancel()
        print("Delta time: ", time.time() - self._init_time)

async def handler(websocket):
    print("[WS-SERVER] client connected")
    while True:
        try:
            msg = await websocket.recv()
            print(f"<: {msg}")
            await websocket.send("Message received. {}".format(msg))
            if(msg == "start"):
                timer = Timer(websocket)
                await timer.start()

        except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
            print("[WS-SERVER] client disconnected")
            break

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 8765):
        print("[WS-SERVER] ready")
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

### Client

```
import asyncio
import websockets


'''async function that recieves and prints messages from the server'''
async def recieve_message(websocket):
    msg1 = await websocket.recv()
    print(f"<: {msg1}")

async def send_message(websocket):
    msg = input("Put your message here: ")
    await websocket.send(msg)
    print(":> Sent message: ", msg)

async def handler():
    uri = "ws://localhost:8765"
    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:

        while True:
            '''run input() in a separate thread'''

            recv_msg, send_msg = await asyncio.gather(
                recieve_message(websocket),
                send_message(websocket),
                return_exceptions=True)

            if(send_msg == "test"):
                print("Supertest")


async def main():
    await handler()
    await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(handler())
    print("[WS-CLIENT] bye")
```

Comment: You're not running input() in a separate thread, you're running it in the same thread in the same asyncio loop, but in a different coroutine.  Running threads requires using the python threading module https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html.  I'm sure there are other posts that would be relevant.  You could try looking here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889527/is-there-a-way-to-use-asyncio-queue-in-multiple-threads